# Magento 2 not showing category menu on home store page

Tags: magento2

Magento not showing category menu

I turn on this features

[image: 1]

but it still doesn't showing menu

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

Please Run below commands:

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:flush

Thanks!!

Comment: Thats not work. I have an extension that adds a page where the categories are displayed, but there is no category menu on the home page. And on the page from this category extension appeared